# Wordpress sub-domain multisite 505 error

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I have a wordpress multisite install in the root of my htdocs set up as

http://localhost.com
and 
http://shop.localhost.com

The shop site works fine however when I visit http://localhost.com I get a 505 error.

I believe something happened to my .htaccess by mistake and am unable to fix it so I really needed some help in problem solving this issue.

I have tried the .htaccess that wordpress provides (below) but this still doesn't get it working! Would really appreciate any help possible!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: To solve issue you need to find out exact error. For that you need to create an error log file in which every error will be displayed in detail and it will also shows in which line error accure. See this article to know how to create error log file for wordpress https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress Mainly the paragraph with the heading/title `Example wp-config.php for Debugging` is the one you need to create error log. Read that paragraph carefully and find your exact error.

Comment: Ah great thank you for the help! There was a fatal error where I had declared a function twice. Not sure why it wasn't showing up in my php_error.log initially! Thanks for the help :)